# Autostart and Getting data from internet in Background

Tags: android

I have app that get data from mysql with GetActivity activity and save in mysqlite and create notifications Now how i want my app run automatic and start GetActivity in background to get data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to look into [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) which are threads that run in the background of Android. From within there you'll be able to load your data from your SQL database.

To take care of the automatic starting, you'll want to look into [BroadcastReceivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), specifically the BOOT_COMPLETED receiver.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add this.

```
public class MyBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ///// Add your Background Service that Sync your data from database or internet//////////
        //// I do the same work it fine work to me.///////
        context.startService(new Intent(context, service_ReloadSqlDB.class));

       /* Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);*/
    }
}
```

Secondly you need to add this in manifest

```
        <receiver
            android:name="com.b2mtech.wrapper.MyBroadcastreceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Hope this help you. Enjoy

http://smrnatore08.wix.com/smr-it-ltd